# move pointer automatically to default button

Tags: mouse, pointers

Is there a way to configure mouse preferences to move the pointer automatically to the default button?

Comment: What do you mean by "default button" ? By automatically, did you mean at startup of Ubuntu / an application ?

Comment: Actually, that's the phrasing used in Windows. When you have a dialog box, there is a "default button". Therefore, I want the pointer to move automatically to the position of that button.

Comment: Default button is the button, which triggers, if I just hit <kbd> enter</kbd>? And this, independent from the language (c, java, python) in which the application was written, and which GUI-lib it uses qt/gtk/swing/awt/swt/tk)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is window manager-dependent. By default, in Ubuntu you're running either Compiz or Metacity. I don't think that either of those WMs has the option you're looking for. But there are many WMs out there. I seem to recall encountering at least one such WM years ago when I used to experiment with window managers. Of course, I no longer remember which one it was, but I suspect a Synaptic and/or Google search for window managers would yield some interesting reading.